# How to get only this value using axios, vuejs and php?

Tags: php, mysql, vue.js, axios

how to retrieve this data with Axios and views.
This is my php code :

```
<?php
include "config.php";

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$request = $data->request;

// Get Number of records
if($request == 1){
  $userNumbers = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userNumbers)){
    $response = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($response);
  exit;
}
```

This is my VueJs code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        var app = new Vue({
          el: '#myapp',
            data: {
              users: ''
            },
            methods: {
                async allUsersNumber(){
                  try {
                    axios.post('api/app.php', {
                    request: 1
                  }).then(response => console.log(response));
                  } catch (error) {
                    console.log("Erreur: " + error);
                  }
                }
            },
          created: function(){
            this.allUsersNumber();
          }
        })
    </script>
```

And here is the result:

[I only want to retrieve the number 3 and display it in an h1 tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0St7.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`3` is coming in data object so you can write the below line to get the value:

console.log(response.data['COUNT(*)']))

Comment: When I display the result in an h1 tag, it is totally empty

Comment: Are you getting the value in console.log?

Comment: It's ok, I was able to fix the problem, Thanks

Comment: How to increment a counter while knowing that it must start with 000.000.000 to then advance to 999.999.999 ?

Answer (score 0):

On server:

```php
$userNumbers = mysql_query($connect, "SELECT count(*) as total from users");
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($userNumbers);
echo $data['total'];
```